# Is it true that if $ \epsilon_t \sim^{iid} (0,1) $, then $ E(\epsilon_t^{2}\epsilon_{t-j}^{2}) = 1 $?

Tags: time-series, expected-value, garch

Under the GARCH($m$,$s$) model, it can be shown that $ E(\eta_t\eta_{t-j}) = E[(a_t^{2}-\sigma_t^{2})(a_{t-j}^{2}-\sigma_{t-j}^{2})] = 0 $.

In my proof attempt, I came across $ E(\epsilon_t^{2}\epsilon_{t-j}^{2}) = 1 $ where $ \epsilon_t \sim^{iid} (0,1) $.

Is it indeed true that if $ \epsilon_t \sim^{iid} (0,1) $, then $ E(\epsilon_t^{2}\epsilon_{t-j}^{2}) = 1 $?

Comment: This is trivial. Use independence of $\epsilon$s, then relationship between raw and central second moments. Done.

Comment: "This is trivial." --> Okay, ouch.

But thanks! I'm going to assume that independence of $\epsilon_t$s implies independence of $\epsilon_t^{2}$s

Comment: Yes, that's right. If the squares were dependent, there's a form of dependence among the unsquared values. If you aren't aware of that fact, then the result is not so obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the OP seems to have a handle on it now, I want to make sure this question has an answer.

First:

$$E(\epsilon_t^{2}) = \text{Var}(\epsilon_t) + [E(\epsilon_t)]^2 = 1+ 0^2 = 1.$$

and

\begin{eqnarray}
E(\epsilon_t^{2}\epsilon_{t-j}^{2}) &=& E(\epsilon_t^{2})\,E(\epsilon_{t-j}^{2})\quad\quad \text{(*)}\\  
&=&1\times 1\\
&=&1
\end{eqnarray}

---

(*) Independence of $\epsilon_t$ and $\epsilon_{t-j}$ implies independence of $\epsilon_t^2$ and $\epsilon_{t-j}^2$

Comment: Note: "independence of $ϵ_t$s implies independence of $ϵ_t^{2}$s" because "If the squares were dependent, there's a form of dependence among the unsquared values." hehe