# Why is E[X+Y|X,Y]=X+Y?

Tags: random-variable, conditional-expectation

Intuitively, it seems obvious, but I am struggling to prove it for the case where $X_1, ..., X_n$ are continuous random variables. I am aware that $E[c(X)|X]=c(X)$. So how would one show that $E[c(X_i) |X_1, ..., X_n] = c(X_i)$ and that $E[c(X_i)+a(X_j)|X_1, ..., X_n] = c(X_i) + a(X_j)$ for $i,j=1, ..., n$?

Comment: This is an immediate consequence of a property of conditional expectation called ["taking out what is known."](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3834154/taking-out-what-is-known)

Comment: @whuber I don't think it's so immediate. I think OP is maybe struggling with how to relate $\sigma(X)$ and $\sigma(Y)$ to $\sigma(X,Y)$ ? idk

Comment: @BCLC I didn't want to say "trivial."  Taking out what is known isn't trivial, but seeing that the sigma-algebra generated by a collection of random variables includes the sigma-algebra generated by any subset of those variables is trivial.

Comment: @whuber lol my very 1st question in stats SE this is what I was told by Glen_b '[This is trivial. Use independence of ϵs, then relationship between raw and central second moments. Done.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/96206/is-it-true-that-if-epsilon-t-simiid-0-1-then-e-epsilon-t2-epsi)'

Answer (score 2):

You can compute an expectation by summing over all possibilities

$$E[f(X,Y)|\text{give some condition}] = \sum_{\text{for all cases of $x,y$}} f(x,y) \cdot p(X=x,Y=y)$$

When the condition is $X=a$ and $Y=b$, then the summation only contains a single term and $p(X=x,Y=y) = 1$ when $x=a$ and $y=b$.

Answer (score 2):

In general if $\mathcal A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on the probability space and a random variable $Z$ is measurable wrt $\mathcal A$ then:$$\mathbb E[Z\mid\mathcal A]=Z$$

Here $X$ and $Y$ are both measurable wrt $\sigma(X,Y)$ and consequently $X+Y$ is measurable wrt $\sigma(X,Y)$.

So in this situation:$$\mathbb E[X+Y\mid X,Y]:=\mathbb E[X+Y\mid\sigma(X,Y)]=X+Y$$

This can be extended to:$$\mathbb E[f(X,Y)\mid X,Y]=f(X,Y)$$for any Borel-measurable function $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$.